# Appropriate test for two test groups, one control group and binary outcome

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data, post-hoc, contrasts

I have the following problem:

We send our Clients an email and offer them some new product. Let's say we want to test 2 email designs. Additionally, we need a control group, since some of the clients would buy a new product even without an email. As a result, we have a binary variable, either the clients bought the product or not.

I would like to test, if any of the 2 emails worked better than the other (i.e. convinced more clients to buy the offered product) and at the same time, if sending the emails is significantly better then not sending them.

So basically, I need three comparisons:

Test 1 vs. Test 2

Test 1 vs. Control

Test 2 vs. Control

What would be the prefered method to do it? I thought about **logistic regression with contrasts**, but how to include the test between the two test groups?

Comment: If you got a contingency table of purchased yes/no, what about just doing two Chi Square Tests of Independence - one between Test 1 vs Test 2, one between Test 1 + Test 2 vs Control? I'm no statistician, but that comes to my mind, first.

Comment: Thanks lukeA! In such case I would need to correct for the alpha error inflation (e.g. Bonferroni). It will work fine with 2 test groups, but it is too conservative, if I had more groups (I might need to divide the significance level by 7 or more, which will basically make everything insignificant). I'm wondering if there's more sophisticated and universal solution.

Comment: That's true. Maybe doing a "global" Chi Square test and looking at the Pearson Standardized Residuals offers some insights about which cells are not independent. But I'm looking forward to alternative approaches, too.